# "Cannot convert a ndarray into a Tensor or Operation." error when trying to fetch a value from session.run in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have created a siamese network in tensorflow. I am calculating the distance between two tensors using the below code:

```
distance = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(question1_predictions, question2_predictions)), reduction_indices=1))
```

I am able to train the model without any errors. In the inference section, I am retrieving the `distance` tensor as below:

```
test_state, distance = sess.run([question1_final_state, distance], feed_dict=feed)
```

Tensorflow is throwing an error:

> Fetch argument array([....], dtype=float32) has invalid type , must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a
>   ndarray into a Tensor or Operation.)

When I print the `distance` tensor, before and after the `session.run` in the training section, it shows as `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`. So the replacement of tensor `distance` with numpy `distance` is happening in the `session.run` of inference section. Following the code from the inference section:

```
with graph.as_default():
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), feed_dict={embedding_placeholder: embedding_matrix})
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('checkpoints'))

    test_state = sess.run(initial_state)

    for ii, (x1, x2, batch_test_ids) in enumerate(get_test_batches(test_question1_features, test_question2_features, test_ids, batch_size), 1):
        feed = {question1_inputs: x1,
                question2_inputs: x2,
                keep_prob: 1,
                initial_state: test_state
               }
        test_state, distance = sess.run([question1_final_state, distance], feed_dict=feed)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you overwrite the Tensor `distance = tf.sqrt(...)` with a numpy array `distance = sess.run(distance)`.

Your loop is the culprit. Change `t_state, distance = sess.run([question1_final_state, distance]` to something like `t_state, distance_other = sess.run([question1_final_state, distance]`

Comment: Yes, that's the reason, but I am not able to figure out the place/operation in the graph that is doing it. I am updating my question with some more details, please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @Mithun the problem is with your loop. I added a few things to my answer